# wxwidgets how to close a thread using wxCloseEvent

Tags: multithreading, wxwidgets

The main program thread (derived from wxConvas) generates the thread for some complicated calculations

When the wxCloseEvent from user arrives I want on this event to delete the thread ,because allowing the thread to continue to work causes memory errors
 want to know how can I find the thread from main thread in runtime and how exactly I destroy/delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not 'find' the thread.  When you construct it, you keep it, or a pointer to it, as an attribute.  When the application closes, you should overide the wxApp::OnExit
() method to delete the thread by calling the method wxThread::Delete() on the stored thread attribute.